# Laravel eloquent check if related model exists

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models, one for tasks and one for user tasks. User tasks sets user_id and task_id so we can track which user has completed which tasks.

Some tasks have a parent task and some do not. If a task has a parent task, we need to check if this parent task has been completed. If it has been completed, we can show this task. If it is not completed, we do not show this task, only the parent task as it needs to be completed first.

This would be pretty easily checked in the view, but I understand that is bad practice.

So I need to understand how to build this query from the controller or model, in basis I need:

If Task parent_task_id is not null

check User Tasks if record exists with this parent_task_id

If so include it.

Can anybody put me on the right path for this on how to build this part either some form in the model, or how to include it in the eloquent query?

Right now I do these checks in the view for each tasks and is working, but I am calling the User Tasks model in the view, basically querying there for each task - it's not very clean.

Example of how I have it in my view right now:

```
if($task->parent_id) {
    $parent = '1';
    if(App\UserTask::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('task_id', '=', $task->parent_id)->exists()) {
        $parentCompleted = '1';
    } 
}
```

This is done in the view foreach($tasks as $task), then a check on parent/parentCompleted where it displays the tasks. I'd like to build this into the query instead.

Comment: Have you looked up the has() or whereHas() methods for the query?

Comment: yes I was starting to build the query whereHas, but I need to first check if it has a parent task. I am unsure on how to start this part. I am using variations of whereDoesntHave already in the query and am familiar with it. But because I need an if check, on a parent_task_id and then check a related model for that parent id, it gets a little confusing for me.

Comment: Can you post your "not very clean" solution as a visual of the problem and the solution?

Comment: @Jared I edited my post to add what I have in my view right now that gives me some variables whether it has a parent, and whether the parent task has been completed. Based on this I know whether to display it or not, if it has a parent task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a relationship setup on the Task model to it's parent? Something like:

```
public function parent() : BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(__CLASS__, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

If so, you can check the parent task's existence and completed status like:

```
null !== $task->parent && $task->parent->status === 'completed'
```

Comment: Yes I have a relationship setup, but the task itself does not have a 'status' field. This is recorded in the User Tasks table. This would still need me to make this check in the view and call the User Tasks model from there, so it is not a real improvement there?

Comment: So you need to check for the existence of a UserTask record through the parent, ok. Try something like `$task->parent->pivot()->exists()`.

Comment: Also try `$task->parent->users()->where('id', $userId)->exists();`

Comment: Thanks btl, I will try this. Pretty sure this is probably the correct way to do it, and not to add it directly in the query.